# Rust shorthand for Result<type, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>

Tags: rust

When doing error catching I usually make a function return a result. But I feel like writing  Result<type, Box<...>> everytime is really verbose, is there some built-in shorthand for this?

```rust
fn something() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  Ok(())
}
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53584631

Comment: Tangential, but I find it much easier to define an `enum` that wraps all of the error types I could ever encounter (one variant per type, each variant wrapping the error) and then `impl From<ErrType> for MyErrorWrapper` for each wrapped `ErrType`. You can still use `?` to bubble up errors and you don't need to box anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just define a type alias with generic arguments. Many crates do like this:

```
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

fn something() -> Result<()> {
  Ok(())
}
```

Comment: For flexibility I'd even recommend using a default value for the error: `type Result<T, E = Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = std::result::Result<T, E>;` that way you can use your "custom" result alias everywhere, it just has a relevant default on the error side. Hell, for convenience you could even default `T = ()` or something.

Answer (score 7):

The [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) crate, written by the author of serde, is designed around an ergonomic alternative to `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` called `anyhow::Error`. It defines `anyhow::Result<T>` as alias for `Result<T, anyhow::Error>`:

```
fn something() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    Ok(())
}
```

The downside is that it's an external crate, although a very widely-used and well-tested one.

The upside is that you get good ergonomics, additional features (such as [`context()` and `with_context()`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.45/anyhow/trait.Context.html) on `Result`), as well as non-trivial optimizations - `anyhow::Error` is a narrow pointer rather than a wide one, so your `Result`s are smaller and more efficient compared to `Box<dyn Error>`.